# Codeigniter Hooks advance

Tags: codeigniter, hook

Hello i am using post_controller hooks to validate user whether logged in or not
But when validation fails i redirect user to login controller....
Now the problem is when it redirect to defaults controller post_controller hooks is called again and in this way infinite loop starts with redirection repeatedly.
i want to call post_controller hook for every controller except login controller....
also is there way that i don't need to load session library again and again because, if user is logged in then it loads session library in post controller as well as via auto-load in config file...
Here is my code

```
    //Hooks
    $hook['post_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'is_login',
                                'function' => 'index',
                                'filename' => 'is_login.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

//Is_Login Hook
class is_login {
function __construct(){
$this->CI =& get_instance();

    if(!isset($this->CI->session))              //Check if session lib is loaded or not
        $this->CI->load->library('session');    //If not loaded, then load it here
}

public function index()
{
    $login_id = $this->CI->session->userdata('login_id');
    $login_flag = $this->CI->session->userdata('logged_in');

       if ($login_flag != TRUE || $login_id == "")
        {
            redirect(site_url().'/welcome_login', 'refresh');

        }           
}
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it is not a good place to use Codeigniter hooks. It is better if you extend the Controller class in your application and in the constructor you can check if user is logged in and redirect to login controller. But no need to extend the login controller from your controller instead extend it from CI_Controller.

Comment: i put same login inside CI_Controller class but same thing happened as redirecting to login controller is also extends CI_Controller

Comment: You understood differently. You need to create your own Controller class MY_Controller in the application/core folder by extending the CI Controller and implement your login code there. Extend all the controllers from the extended (MY_Controller) except the login controller.

Comment: Thanx nish every one was saying to save MY_controller in application/libraries you rightly pointed out to save it in core i solved my problem thanx a lot

Comment: If this answer is working please make it correct answer so that it will others.

Answer (score 1):

I validate logins by hooks without problem. I just generate the login view when logged out and `exit` the application so that the only thing showing is the login, and the controller (and rest) gets ignored.

There's no need for redirect, really.

Comment: i didnot want to load view for login due to some reasons have you any other solution

Comment: Only redirect if uri isn't login. `$CI =& get_instance(); if ($CI->uri->segment(1) == 'login') return;`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->CI->uri->segment(1) != 'auth') {

    //Authenticate
    if (empty($user->user_id))redirect('auth');

}
```