# Codeigniter find whether user logged in or not

Tags: php, codeigniter, lamp

In codeigniter I am trying to include a Logger library and in the below code I need to check whether a user has logged in or not and if so, find his user id.

```
  <?php
    class Logger {

private $CI;

public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}

public function request_logger() {
    $uri = $this->CI->uri->uri_string();
    $ip="";
    $userID="";
    //$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $params = trim(print_r($this->CI->input->post(), TRUE));

    log_message('info', '==============');
    log_message('info', 'URI: ' . $uri);
    log_message('info', '--------------');
    log_message('info', 'PARAMS:' . $params);
    log_message('info', 'IP:' . $ip);
    log_message('info', '==============');
    //if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    if(isset($_POST['user_id']))
    {
        log_message('info', '<== Inside loggedin loop ==>');
        $userID=$this->input->post('user_id');



     }
        log_message('info', 'USERID' . $userID);

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use Sessions?

Comment: i am new to code igniter and php5 can u please give me an example

Comment: I got the answer to the following problem from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408379/codeigniter-hooks-advance Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use codeigniter Session class.
you can create new session with user data,like this

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

and you can access this data via,

```
$userId = $this->session->userdata('userid');
```

Visit this User Guide[Codeignitor Session](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: But to do this i have to extend my class to CI_CONTROLLER right?

Comment: if you're trying to write a library, why extend CI_Controller?

Comment: So,you are trying to write your own Library?

Comment: yes.And it is a hook actually.as in  http://techtots.blogspot.in/2011/12/logging-request-parameters-in.html and here i want to find out whether a user has logged in or not and if so what is his userid

Comment: your 'request_logger()' function now analyzing the input post values.If you wand to check the login you must access  the Session Class from this hooks.plz check the [hooks doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html). how to access  this on hooks

Comment: k thanks i got this resolved from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408379/codeigniter-hooks-advance